# Response from PHP not as expected

Tags: php, json

I am trying to send data from a database to an app based on what was send from the app to the server like so:

```
$search_bp=$_POST['search_bp'];
$search_trig = 0;

    if(strcmp($search_bp,"1")==true){
    //decisions that could set search_trig = 1;
    //eg
    if(strcmp($_POST['EStype'],'Event')){
       if(strcmp($_POST['type'],'Any')==false){
           if(strcmp($_POST['type'],$row["type"])==false){
           $search_trig=1;//doesnt match specs
          }
      }
    }   
    }
if($search_trig == 0){
    $event["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $event["name"] = $row["name"];
    $event["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];
    $event["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
    $event["pavement"] = $row["pavement"];
    $event["traffic"] = $row["traffic"];
    $event["environment"] = $row["environment"];
    $event["image_b64"] = $row["image_b64"];
    $event["date"] = $row["date"];
    $event["time"] = $row["time"];
    $event["type"] = $row["type"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["events"], $event);
}
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

What is going wrong is that it `strcmp($search_bp,"1")` seems to always be false even though I am sending it as

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("search_bp",  Integer.toString(search_bp)));
```

Where I know `search_bp=1`, I just don't know too much about php so I'm pretty sure it is just my syntax.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Comment: "seems to always be false"...are you sure? You do realise there's nothing inside this IF statement: `if(strcmp($search_bp,"1")==true) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Note That **strcmp** not return true or false:

It return as follow

```
0 - if the two strings are equal
<0 - if string1 is less than string2
>0 - if string1 is greater than string2
```

You need to change something like below:

```
if(strcmp($search_bp,"1")==0){
//
}
```

In your case you can also use == operator.

Please Note : **==** only returns **true** or **false**, it doesn't tell you which is the "greater" string

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` returns an integer not a boolean. 
`Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.`

Technically, you should simply be checking as `if ($search_bp == "1") {`

If we were to dissect your statement in php's loose type world you can see your mistake.

```
`strcmp` will return 0 because they do match. 
0 = false 
1 = true
```

so `if(strcmp($search_bp,"1")==true){` solves to `if(0==true){`, then `if(0==1){` which would not meet the condition.